# How do I display the console output to HTML in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

So I'm using Django framework to display the console output to the HTML. To execute the command, I'm using the `check_output` of `subprocess` module in Python. Which receives the input from the HTML input form. The problem is that I only see "`None`" on the HTML page, which is the default value of `output` in `views` file.
Below is the code of the views file and HTML file. I'm a novice in this so I'd appreciate your assistance.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .forms import command_form
import subprocess as sp


# Create your views here.

def welcome_page(request):
    output=""
    if request.method == "POST":
        myform = command_form(request.POST)
        if (myform.is_valid()):
            execute_command = myform.cleaned_data['cmd_string']
            output = sp.check_output(execute_command, shell=True)
        else:
            myform = command_form()
        return render(request, 'ovs/welcome.html', {'output': output})
    else:
        return render(request, 'ovs/welcome.html', {})
```

**welcome.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>welcome to ovs GUI</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Choose the option:</h3>
    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        Enter the command: <input type="text" name="cmd_string" id="cmd_string"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Run"/>
    </form>
    <h3>{{ output }}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

**forms**

```
from django import forms


class command_form(forms.Form):
    command = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is that's not working. What's your problem?

Comment: My problem is that data is that the console output is not getting displayed. It's always giving the default value of "output" on HTML page. Which makes me skeptical if it even can parse the data from post method.

Comment: @AnandTyagi. Did any of the below answers worked for you?

Comment: @nik_m Yes, Your answer worked fine. Thanks a million

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not rendering the form field correctly to your HTML. You have created a `command_form` form and you never exploit it. However, you should use camel case name for python `class`es, like this `CommandForm`.

Inside your HTML, write this:

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    Enter the command: {{ myform }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit_cmd" value="Run" />
</form>
{% if output %}<h3>{{ output }}</h3>{% endif %}
{% if exit_code %}<h3>Your command returned an error: {{ error_msg }}</h3>{% endif %}
```

`{{ my_form }}` will expand, automatically, to `<input type="text" ...>`

Now, write your `welcome_page` view like this:

```
def welcome_page(request):
    output = ""
    # Initialize the form. At this point you have an unbound/invalid form
    myform = command_form()  # better write it as CommandForm

    if request.method == "POST":
        myform = command_form(request.POST)
        if myform.is_valid():
            # execute_command variable, should now contain the command typed by the user in the text box
            execute_command = myform.cleaned_data['command']
            try:
                # If the return code is non-zero, CalledProcessError will be raised
                output = sp.check_output(execute_command, shell=True)
            except sp.CalledProcessError:
                exit_code, error_msg = output.returncode, output.output
        else:
            # Do something when the form is not valid. Maybe add a message or something, or not implement else clause at all.
    return render(request, 'ovs/welcome.html', locals())
```

Warning! As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) say:

> Using `shell=True` can be a security hazard.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not showing the input box when I change the HTML as you said. what should I do?

Comment: Oh. A damn typo. Updated my answer. Instead of `{{ my_form }}` changed to `{{ myform }}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST framework to return a Response so you don't have to worry about handling it in HTML. Just install the rest_framework and do this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

return Response(data)
```

Comment: But I need to show the output below my HTML data. ie. I want to show it below the form which takes the command line as text.

Answer (score 1):

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from test.forms import CommadForm
import subprocess as sp

def welcome_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        myform = CommadForm(request.POST)
        if myform.is_valid():
            execute_command = myform.cleaned_data['command']
            try:
                output = sp.check_output(execute_command, shell=True)
            except sp.CalledProcessError:
                output = 'No such command'
        else:
            myform = CommadForm()
        return render(request, 'ovs/welcome.html', {'output': output})
    else:
        return render(request, 'ovs/welcome.html')

forms.py

class CommadForm(forms.Form):
    command = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: html page will be the same which you have used